# Port 1433 seems to be closed, but it's enabled on Windows Server 2003 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, firewall

today I update the RTM build without any Service Pack to SP1, so Windows Firewall comes available, when I add a new Exception for SQL Server (local) like on Windows XP, I think that it will be work fine than on my local pc but it went wrong, I can ping and do remote desktop connections (3389) also on telnet this port is working but when I try with SQL Default port (1433) it seems to be closed or not mapped cause every configuration on SQL is accepting by default (1433).

Thanks for helpings me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have helped it you had said which version of SQL Server you are trying to install.  If you are using SQL 2000 on Windows 2003 you have to install SP2 or higher before SQL can be connected to remotly.

Answer (score 1):

You can see if your server is listening on post 1433 with netstat -a. That would probably be a good place to start, if it's not listening there may be a problem with SQL configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the port is not 1433

Look in the registry using regedit.exe at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp.

One of the nameValue pairs has name TcpPort and a value, which is the port that the SQL Server is listening on (mine was set to 1030).